# Exchange 2010 error during setup: "Failed to mount database" "edb is missing but still has transaction log files"

Tags: exchange, exchange-2010

```
--------------------------------------------------------
Microsoft Exchange Error
--------------------------------------------------------
Failed to mount database 'Public Folder Database 1471458426'.
```

To whom it may respond to,

While trying to setup exchange 2010 at command :

```
New-MailboxDatabase -Server 'EXCSRV1' -Name 'Database02' -EdbFilePath 'C:\Program Files\Microsoft\Exchange Server\V14\Mailbox\Database02\Database02.edb' -LogFolderPath 'C:\Program Files\Microsoft\Exchange Server\V14\Mailbox\Database02'
```

I got this error:

```
--------------------------------------------------------
Microsoft Exchange Error
--------------------------------------------------------
Failed to mount database 'Public Folder Database 1471458426'.

Public Folder Database 1471458426
Failed
Error:
Couldn't mount the database that you specified. Specified database: Public Folder Database 1471458426; Error code: An Active Manager operation failed. Error: The database action failed. Error: The mount operation is being prevented for database 'Public Folder Database 1471458426' because its database file at 'C:\Program Files\Microsoft\Exchange Server\V14\Mailbox\Public Folder Database 1471458426\Public Folder Database 1471458426.edb' is missing, but still has transaction log files, with the highest generation number being 0x13. Please either recover the database file from a backup, or remove the log files if your intention is to mount a newly-created empty database.. [Database: Public Folder Database 1471458426, Server: EXCSRVM.fasdat.com].
```

There are .jrs files , .jhk files and some other binary files but there are no .log files.

What are the steps to recover from this step and continue to setup?

Answer (score 2):

If you don't want that public folder database, simply do what it says and delete the `.log` files associated with the database, which IIRC should be in a folder of their own. I'd recommend moving them somewhere safe for a while rather than deleting them - just in case.

If you deleted the `.edb` file yourself, then you should be fine to delete the log files too (make sure you deleted it from the Exchange Management Console as well). If you didn't delete the `.edb` file it complains is missing, you may have something more peculiar going on that should probably be investigated.

Comment: not deleted edb on purpose, seems to be deleted after the command. will try to do as you have told to. thank you for your concern. will post the results.

Comment: sorry had to delete all config and start over.

Answer (score 0):

Hopefully you have a backup, and you will need to restore the .ebd file from that backup.  Then once you start the services and mount the database, exchange should automatically go into recovery mode and roll the log files back onto the .edb file to bring it current.

Comment: What if there is no backup, since it is a new installation and shadow volume is disabled?

Comment: We are trying to do this installation on Vmware Essentials Plus, does it make difference on requirements?

Comment: VMWare should not make a difference; if this is a new installation, and there is nothing in the Public Folders Database that you require, then you can simply delete the PFD from the Exchange Management Console.

Answer (score 0):

If you can't find the old database then I would suggest to use dial-tone restore.  Move all the log file to other folder, and then use Mount-Database with -Force switch to create a new clean database to start the communication between users. Then you can do a recovery restore and merge the old data back into their mailboxes.